# Как через rest api, отправить в чат открытых линий, сообщение в режиме скрытого сообщения от клиента?

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Суть в том, что ни где не нашел информации как отправить сообщение через апи в режиме скрытого от клиента. Я точно знаю, что через апи это можно сделать.
использую метод

> imconnector.send.messages

[image: первых два сообщения скрыты, два других открытые (сделано через ui)]

Что хочу получить, мне надо когда приходит первое сообщение от клиент и создается сделка с контактом, показывать некое системное сообщение для оператора, которое не должно показываться клиенту, только оператору.

есть такой метод

> imopenlines.session.mode.silent

но это не то, во-первых для того, что бы этот мод включить оператор должен принять диалог, иначе не работает, во-вторых в при включении данного режима появляется запись, что включился режим, а в других интеграциях я вижу, что этого не происходит. Идет первоначальное сообщение с системной инфой сразу в режиме скрытого сообщения. затем уже создаются лиды, контакты итп.

еще в при передаче сообщения, можно передать информацию о чате в которой есть ссылка и имя чата
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но ни как информация о имени чата или эта ссылка не влияет на название чата и ни где эта ссылка не показывается. Вопрос зачем имя чата тогда передавать если чат все равно назовётся так как называется контакт. И для чего эта ссылка нужна?

Спасибо всем кто поможет!